# Script to convert html into jQuery format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transform, translate

I'm trying to write a quick javascript program to covert HTML into jQuery format as I don't like pasting HTML in code and its becoming tedious to convert html to jQuery format every time I need to make something dynamic but already have the html, from pre-written templates ect (plus html is nicer to actually write).

Warning: its written pretty badly, I was trying to get it done quickly and it's nearly there for my purposes just got kinda stuck on the last recursive bit.

The javascript:

```
var openTag = false;
var openQuote = false;
var openQuotePlace = 0;
var lastSpace = 0;
var startToken = 0;
var html =''
var attrs = {}
const domElements = []
var firstSpace = true;
var attr = '';

var rootElement = null;
for(var i = 0; i < input.length;i++){

    if(input[i] == '<'){
        openTag = true;
        startToken = i+1;
        firstSpace = true;
    }

    if(openTag && ((i+1) < input.length && input[(i+1)] == '/')){
        openTag = false;
        startToken = 0;
        html = '';
        attrs = {}
        openQuote = false;
        openQuotePlace = 0;

    }

    if(openTag && input[i] == '>'){
        console.log('here')
        openTag = false
        startToken = 0;
        const obj = {jQuery:'$(\'<'+ html + '>\',' + JSON.stringify(attrs) + ')',children:[]}

        if(!rootElement)
            rootElement = obj;
        else if(html){
            rootElement.children.push(obj);
            domElements.push(rootElement);
            rootElement = obj;
        }
        html = '';
        attrs = {}
        openQuote = false;
        openQuotePlace = 0;
    }

    if(openTag && (input[i] == "\"" || input[i] == "'")){
        openQuote = !openQuote;
        if(openQuote){
            openQuotePlace = i;
        }else{
            if(openQuotePlace != 0){
                attrs[attr] = input.substring(openQuotePlace+1,i);
                openQuotePlace = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(openTag && input[i] == ' '){
        if(firstSpace){
            html = input.substring(startToken,i);
            firstSpace = false;
        }
        lastSpace = i;
    }

    if(openTag && input[i] == '='){
        attr = input.substring(lastSpace+1,i);
    }

}

function buildRecursive(root,arr){
    if(root.children.length == 0){
        return arr.join('') + '))';
    }
    const jquery = root.jQuery;
    arr.push(jquery);
    arr.push('.append(')
    for(var i = 0; i < root.children.length;i++){
        buildRecursive(root.children[i],arr);
    }
    arr.push(')');
    return arr.join('') + ')';
}

if(domElements.length > 0)
    console.log(buildRecursive(domElements[0],[]));
```

The html input:

```
const input = '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">'+
                        '<a href="#">'+
                            '<img src="http://wanderluxe.theluxenomad.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/http-www.urchinbali.comgallery.jpg" class="img-responsive img-box img-thumbnail"/>'+
                        '</a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">'+
                        '<div class="list-group">' +
                            '<div class="list-group-item">' +
                                '<div class="row-picture">'+
                                    '<a href="#" title="sintret">'+
                                        '<img class="circle img-thumbnail img-box" src="http://sintret.com/img/andy.jpg" alt="sintret">'+
                                    '</a>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="row-content">'+
                                    '<div class="list-group-item-heading">'+
                                        '<a href="#" title="sintret">'+
                                            '<small>sintret</small>'+
                                        '</a>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<small>'+
                                        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3 days ago via <span class="twitter"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/sintret" alt="sintret" title="sintret">@sintret</a></span>'+
                                        '<br>'+
                                        '<span class="explore"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i> <a href="#">Explore 2 places </a></span>'+
                                    '</small>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'
```

The first element of the domElements array JSON stringified looks like this (root element points to its children which in turn point to their children nodes.. and so on):

```
{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"row\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<a>',{\"href\":\"#\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"list-group\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"list-group-item\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"row-picture\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<a>',{\"href\":\"#\",\"title\":\"sintret\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"row-content\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<div>',{\"class\":\"list-group-item-heading\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<a>',{\"href\":\"#\",\"title\":\"sintret\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<i>',{\"class\":\"glyphicon glyphicon-time\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<span>',{\"class\":\"twitter\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<i>',{\"class\":\"fa fa-twitter\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<span>',{\"class\":\"explore\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<i>',{\"class\":\"glyphicon glyphicon-th\"})","children":[{"jQuery":"$('<a>',{\"href\":\"#\"})","children":[]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

finally the final output:

```
$('<div>',{"class":"row"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3"}).append($('<a>',{"href":"#"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"list-group"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"list-group-item"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"row-picture"}).append($('<a>',{"href":"#","title":"sintret"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"row-content"}).append($('<div>',{"class":"list-group-item-heading"}).append($('<a>',{"href":"#","title":"sintret"}).append($('<i>',{"class":"glyphicon glyphicon-time"}).append($('<span>',{"class":"twitter"}).append($('<i>',{"class":"fa fa-twitter"}).append($('<span>',{"class":"explore"}).append($('<i>',{"class":"glyphicon glyphicon-th"}).append()))))))))))))))))
```

The problem is that the final structure of the jQuery is wrong, as it's not closing the brackets correctly. I was wondering if someone could provide advice so that I can complete it, thanks!

Comment: In my opinions it's always a bad idea to have you html markup inside a javascript file. Same goes for javascript inside an html file. Either use a framework that supports html templates (like angular) or load the html from file with $.get or something similar. First google hit: https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template

Comment: Yeah, I'm using EJS as a templating engine at the moment however unfortunately because of the nature of some things in the website I'm developing I have to resort to AJAX calls to the server rather than passing the data to the view, which means that displaying via the templating engine isn't possible and must be done dynamically.

Comment: Aha! I wasn't aware such a thing existed, that actually looks quite promising and like something I could use. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: WHY? For the love of eveything holy. What is the purpose of this overly complicated code to get/manipulate content on an existing webpage?